# Saving arrays of data to a database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-edittext

I have 4 EditText fields that the user will input data for. I want to be able to save the data to a database internally (on the device).

Here are the declarations (during my onCreate):

```
String[] debtName = new String[10];
double[] debtAmount = new double[10];
int[] debtRate = new int[10];
double[] debtPayment = new double[10];
int trigger = 0;
```

Later, I pull the data from the EditTexts (during a ButtonOnClick):

```
EditText editDebtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtName);
debtName[trigger] = editDebtName.getText().toString();

EditText editDebtAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtAmount);
String debtAmountStr = editDebtAmount.getText().toString();
debtAmount[trigger] = Double.parseDouble(debtAmountStr);

EditText editDebtRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtRate);
String debtRateStr = editDebtRate.getText().toString();
debtRate[trigger] = Integer.parseInt(debtRateStr);

EditText editDebtPayment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtPayment);
String debtPaymentStr = editDebtPayment.getText().toString();
debtPayment[trigger] = Double.parseDouble(debtPaymentStr);
```

I'm looking for any simple resources on how to save these pieces of data to a db (preferable without parsing the data anymore).

Comment: Have you implemented your SQLite DB logic, like table creation and some CRUD operations?

Comment: assume I have done nothing with DB. I'm actually completely unfamiliar with them in Java.. I can manipulate in PHP a little, but not enough to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without parsing, the data you will recieve will be in the form `CharSequence[]` (which later you can transform in to string by `toString()` method), and this is recommended only if you are not going to do any arithematic operations with those integers and doubles. But if you want to do, you have to definitely go with parsing these values.

Check this link on developer.android.com: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Also check these links for database tutorials:

1. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html‎
2. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Can you confirm - Are DB only able to retain the same type of variables as sharedpreference?

Comment: Database in Android is SQLite (not MySQL as one of your question tags). You can check the supported data type [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). However SQLite is [typeless](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html).